# SQL TRIGGER ON UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert

Hey guys i am trying to make a trigger to update the feild Bill.BillAmmount everytime a new row is added to Reading
The feild should = (Reading.MeterReading - Reading.LastMeterReading)*Resedent.Rate )

REDEDENT
BILL
READING

are the 3 tables
also thankyou sooo much

````
AFTER INSERT ON Reading
Begin
    UPDATE bill
    SET bill.BillAmount = (SELECT (Reading.MeterReading - Reading.LastMeterReading)*Resedent.Rate 
    FROM Reading, Resedent
    WHERE Reading.ReadingID = ReadingID AND Resedent.AccountID = AccountID)
End;

DROP TRIGGER BILLAMOUNT_ON_INSERT; ```
````

Comment: It's usually a mistake to *store* that which can be *calculated*. All you do by storing it is introduce the opportunity for it to be inconsistent.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. Is this SQL Server?

Comment: Its using Oracle SQL

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a trigger should be referring to `:NEW` (or perhaps `:OLD`).  In addition, Oracle doesn't support `FROM` in `UPDATE` statements.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
Begin
    UPDATE bill b
        SET BillAmount = (SELECT (:new.MeterReading - :new.LastMeterReading) * rs.Rate 
                          FROM Resedent rs
                          WHERE rs.ReadingID = :new.AccountID
                         )
        WHERE b.AccountId = :new.AccountId
End;
```

However, without more information about your data model, it is hard to be specific about what you really want to do.